# Elasticsearch query_string search using wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch when queried with the following returns no results.

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "filtered":{  
      "query":{  
        "bool":{  
          "should":[  
            {  
              "query_string":{  
                "query":"a*",
                "analyze_wildcard":true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**When I use "al*" instead of "a*", I am getting proper results.** This is happening for "a*" only. When I use any others like "b*" or "c*", etc. the results are proper

I am using elasticsearch version 0.90.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `a` is a stop word and gets eliminated by the standard analyzer that analyzes your query. You can probably get around this by specifying a different analyzer, such as `keyword` instead of using the `standard` one. Another option is to leave `analyze_wildcard` set to `false`.

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "filtered":{  
      "query":{  
        "bool":{  
          "should":[  
            {  
              "query_string":{  
                "query":"a*",
                "analyze_wildcard":true,
                "analyzer": "keyword"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Can you please explain how "a.*" in the query above searches for.  I have a record "A. J. Satya" and it is not getting returned when searched using "a.*" in the above query.

Comment: The problem is that at indexing time the value `A. J. Satya` will get tokenized as the tokens `j` and `satya` because `a` is an english stop word and gets discarded. You probably need to change the analyzer you're using at indexing time too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.